# how to get label text inside repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, text, label, repeater

I am trying to get the text of a lable when someone clicks on a link button:

this is my code :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('[id*="lnkbtn_Remove"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var id = $("span[id*=lbl_Reference]").text();
            alert(id); 
        });
    });
```

But this gets me all the reference in the reapter as I am using "*". Is there anyway to get the actual reference on the row it has been clicked. Here is my html:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="test">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="width: 230px;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Len" runat="server" CssClass="font_bold"></asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Reference" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <div style="width: 80px;">
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_Remove" runat="server" CssClass="rpt_item_Remove">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by something like this,

```
 var lablelId = $(this).closest('.test').find('[id*=lbl_Reference']).attr('id');
 var lablelText = $(this).closest('.test').find('[id*=lbl_Reference]').text();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this on click function but get empty string. would this work with my click function above with "*"

Comment: Do you have some text in label, if not then put some text in label and check, if you get it back?

Comment: I get this error in firebug : Timestamp: 04/12/2012 15:45:04
Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id=^lbl_Reference

Comment: I think it should be `'[id$="lbl_Reference"]'` - `$` instead of the `^` - as the server ID goes at the end of the client ID, no?

Comment: Put some text in label like <asp:Label ID="lbl_Reference" runat="server">test </asp:Label>

Comment: I did still empty messagebox

Comment: ah if i put * I get the value of each row.... :  $('[id*="lnkbtn_Remove"]').click(function (event) {
var lablelText = $(this).closest('.test').find('[id*="lbl_Reference"]').text();

Comment: what is the difference between *, $ and ^

Comment: ^ is used for startsWith and * is for contains you can read more over here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I figured out the reason for element being not matached, As Rawling said the id generated by asp.net ends with the orignal id so we need to use $ instead of ^

Comment: Thanks @Rawling you are absolutely right, I just realized I had to use $

Comment: Okay use * agian changed my answer have used asp.net for some, I am so sorry for being guessing

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to find how many column set checked and if checked then want to find label value that nested inside repeater table row PFB :-

```
var chkValue = $("#TableID [id*=chkBoxId]");
 for (var i = 0; i < chkValue.length; i++) {
     if (chkValue[i].checked) 
       $('#TableID tr:eq(' + (i+1) + ') td:eq(0)').find('[id*=lblIds]').text() ;
```